# Using Gradle plugin from a custom Maven repository

Tags: java, maven, gradle

I'm working within a limited dev environment that uses a private Maven repository. In it is hosted a Gradle plugin that I'm trying to use. However, I don't think it's following the expected naming and directory structure for Gradle plugins, so my build fails when I use the Plugin DSL. In the Maven repository, the plugin is structured as something like:

```
com.mydomain.project:mydomain-plugin:1.0.0
```

When I refer to this plugin using the Gradle plugin DSL using the following definition:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.mydomain.project' version '1.0.0'
}
```

I get an error with my build complaining that it can't find `com.mydomain.project:com.mydomain.poject.gradle.plugin:1.0.0`. However, there doesn't seem to be a way through the plugin DSL to indicate that the plugin uses a different artifact id pattern. Any ideas how to resolve this?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `pluginManagement { }` to specify additional repositories for Gradle plugins.

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'https://my-company-maven-repo.com/'
        }
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}
```

See [Custom Plugin Repositories](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:custom_plugin_repositories)
 for more details.

That's the first step, second you need to ensure you are publishing two artifacts in order to use the `plugins { }` DSL:

1. [Plugin Marker Artifact](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:plugin_markers)
2. Gradle plugin JAR itself

Both artifacts are created for you by the [Java Gradle Plugin Development plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_gradle_plugin.html#java_gradle_plugin). If you are not using the plugin, then you will need to create the plugin marker artifact yourself.